# asp:LinkButton created via literal control will not fire code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a requirement to add an ASP:LinkButton dynamically to a web page using a LiteralControl. First I generate a unique ID for the control and then add it as follows:

```
string criteriaDeleteButtonID = "lnkDelete_" + dsCriteria.Tables[0].Rows[intCriteria]["CriteriaID"].ToString();
 pnlContent.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<asp:LinkButton id=\"" + criteriaDeleteButtonID + "\" OnClick=\"LinkButton_Click\" runat=\"server\" class=\"btn btn-danger\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash\"></i> </asp:LinkButton> </div>"));
```

In my code behind I have the following

```
    public void LinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton tmpLinkButton = (LinkButton)sender;
    string[] idvars = tmpLinkButton.ID.Split('_');
    int criteriaID = Convert.ToInt32(idvars[1].ToString());

    clsDataAccess tmpClsData = new clsDataAccess();
    bool result = tmpClsData.DeleteCriteria(criteriaID);
    buildForm();

}
```

No matter what I do I don't seem to be able to make the code behind fire. If I add the *same* HTML manually to the form the code behind fires but if I add the same code dynamically with the LiteralControl the event will not fire.

I am generating the form dynamically in the Page_Load. I have tried in the Page_Int with no luck. The browser console reports the following: Uncaught ReferenceError: LinkButton_Click is not defined. Any thoughts?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18018993/literal-control-with-an-asp-button

Comment: Server-side control as a text of literal control does not make any sense. What is your real requirement? Dynamically add a link button to the page?

Comment: Thanks Diginari and Andrei. Yes real requirement is to dynamically add a link button to the page. The page is quite complex and I am building up the html using a string builder and writing the string builder to the page via the literal at the end. I was hoping to not have to add normal controls to the page as I will not be able to use the string builder. I might be out of luck with this one...

Comment: @Rusty007, yes you are out of luck. For server-side controls they need to be added to the control tree via normal Controls.Add methods. If you use Literal with some text instead, the control you really need is just a piece of text from ASP.NET, and does not exist strictly speaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the MSDN:https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx

LiteralControl (Class)

Represents HTML elements, text, and any other strings in an ASP.NET page that **do not** require processing on the server.

Code behind obviously needs procesing on server side.

Comment: Really appreciate your help @Andrei; @Jerry